# Lebesgue Integral over on two dimensions

Tags: measure-theory

Using super level sets find the Lebesgue measure of $$\int_B x-y^2 dxdy$$

where $B=\{(x,y):0 \lt x \lt 1, -\sqrt{x} \lt y \lt \sqrt{x}\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$

I am finding a difficulty in find the super level set. Any hints so that I can proceed.

Comment: We can define it as: $\{y\in(-\sqrt{x}, \sqrt{x}):x-y^2 >t)\}$, where $t>0$. The measure  I am trying is one dimensional.

Comment: Yes, the bounds are correct.

Comment: I can write the integral as $\int_{-1}^{1}dx [ \int_{0}^{\infty} m\{y\in(-\sqrt{x}, \sqrt{x}):x-y^2 >t)\} dt]$

Comment: are you sure you copied the exercise correctly? Note that if $x<0$ then $\sqrt x$ is not defined in $\Bbb R$

Comment: Yeah, I think $0 \lt x \lt 1$.

Comment: it doesn't make sense to use "super level sets" to solve this integral because the measure of such a level set will be as harder to calculate as the integral that you want to solve